# Skip/Take not returning what is expected

Tags: c#, linq

New to C# (coming from Python where slicing was more straight forward).

```
 using System.Linq;

 string[] listSlice = { "aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff", "gg" };

 var result1 = listSlice.Skip(2).Take(2);
 Console.WriteLine(result1);
```

I would expect the above to return "cc", "dd"  but instead it is returning:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+ListPartition`1[System.String]
```

Am I missing a step?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result1));` - you should join items into `string` with some delimiter (here it is `", "`)

Comment: The problem is that you need to format the results into something you can print.

Comment: Got it.  Thank you both!

Comment: Most LINQ methods return an `IEnumerable<T>`. you need to explicitly use `.ToArray()` or `.ToList` to get an array or list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, typically you'd use a `for` loop to iterate over the results, or use `String.Join()` to combine the results into one value.

Both approaches are shown below:

```
string[] listSlice = { "aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff", "gg" };
var result1 = listSlice.Skip(2).Take(2);

foreach (var value in result1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", result1));
```